# Filter a has_many association on a field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models :

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :destination
end

class Destination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

My "event" model has a "activated" (boolean) field, and i want to show only the activated events when i call Destination.events. How can i always filter on the activated field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `:conditions` option:

```
class Destination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, :conditions => { :activated => true }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibility would be `default_scope`, e.g `default_scope where('activated = 1')`

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class

Comment: Better take the one from @Jordan